# Etymology of bateren (伴天連 / 破天連)

Tags: etymology, loanwords, archaic-language, religion

The archaic Japanese word *bateren* [伴天連 / 破天連](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%A0%B4%E5%A4%A9%E9%80%A3) (referring to a missionary [Jesuit] priest) is derived from the Portuguese *padre*.

The Portuguese word notably does not contain or end in a nasal consonant, and all other [Portuguese loans to Japanese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Japanese_words_of_Portuguese_origin) I'm familiar with only end in ん when the Portuguese word itself has an n/m or nasal vowel.

Given this, why was it adapted as *bateren* as opposed to the expected **batere / *patere*?

Answer (score 2):

My hypothesis is that it was influenced by the similar word, *iruma**n*** (イルマン / 入満 / 伊留満 / 由婁漫) (from pt. *irm**ã**o*, "a layman or scholastic training for the priesthood", note the nasal vowel), as this word was borrowed at the same time and in the same context.

However, I found no direct evidence to support this claim.

---

<sup>**Sources:**</sup>
<sup>- [*Japanese Traditions of Christianity*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nPODDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq="bateren") (p.10, n.12, 13)</sup>
<sup>- [*The Kakure Kirishitan of Japan: A Study of Their Development, Beliefs and ...*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=OfqzAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq="bateren") (p.69)</sup>
<sup>- [*Women Religious Leaders in Japan's Christian Century, 1549-1650*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=saX0gHc91fkC&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq="bateren") (p.2, n.6)</sup>